# How to efficiently find which array in a set of array has members

Tags: arrays, algorithm, messaging

How do I efficiently find which array in a list of array has members.

The context is for message brokering. I have a list of queue and need to periodically push their content to consumers, but since the number of queues can be large, I want to quickly find out which ones have elements in them.

My only solution currently is to basically keep a separate list which keeps track of which array still has content in it, but was curious about alternatives, and it just bugs the hell out of me ;)

I am using javascript but am hoping for a more general idea of which algorihtm should I look into.

Comment: Please clarify "My only solution currently is to basically keep track of everything"?

Comment: What makes you think a solution will be anything other than "search each array"?

Comment: @axblount I can think of an obvious method: just store another set that only contains nonempty queues. When you add/remove a queue, add/remove it from both sets as applicable. I'm wondering why this wouldn't work for the OP.

Comment: It just seems like there has to be better ways of approaching this type of problem then "run through every member, every time". I don't know for sure though, which is why I am asking.

Comment: @imallett indeed, that does work, but it means a lot of bookkeeping. I am wondering if there are slightly less efficient, but more generic approaches.

Comment: What's is your current complexity to check if the array contains element or not ?

Comment: Can you know from the list how much a each list contains or just (yes/no) for contains and doesn't contain /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to make this language-agnostic and keep my answer short and simple.

Maintain a parallel data-structure: another set storing array IDs, but *only those of arrays that are nonempty*.

- When you make a new (empty) array, add it to the first set only.
- When you add to an array, add it to the second set iff it's not already there.
- When you remove from an array, if the array is now empty, remove it from the second set.
- When you delete an array, remove it from the the first set (and the second, if it's there).

If you're using a hashset for this second set, insertion and deletion times don't change.  This is the most efficient thing one could ask for, and a hybrid datastructure of this ilk is necessary AFAICT.

You can then find all nonempty arrays by iterating over the second set.